# Raw types, unbounded wilcard and bounded wildcard

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have a quick question as below:
Here's a simple examples about this whole issues:

```
List a = new ArrayList();
List <?> b;
List <? extends Object> c;
```

According to Java SCJP by khalid mughal (a very good book!):

```
a = b; // ok. Widening conversion.
b = a; // ok too. No unchecked warning.

b = c; // ok
c = b; // ok

c=a; // ok but now will issue a unchecked warning. // clause 1
```

I do understand that any raw types (example a) when assigned to any bounded wilcard references, a unchecked warning is issues (since the content in that raw type a could be anything).

My questions is since c is the highest upper bound (? extends objects), shouldn't a be able to assigned to c without that warning?

Comment: I have no idea what this is about, but do you actually mean the highest upper bound?  Usually in typing it would be more natural to talk about the _least_ upper bound (the join of the set of types with respect to some partial order over it).

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow.com! Unfortunately, your question does not make sense as it is now. Please clarify it (at least link to the post you cite, fix the repetition between 2. & 3.). Otherwise your post will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly (and I really don't think I do), there appear to be two instances in which interaction with raw types could cause an unchecked warning to occur, according to [this page](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#110257):

> - An invocation of a method or constructor of a raw type generates an unchecked warning if erasure changes any of the types of any of the arguments to the method or constructor.
> - An assignment to a field of a raw type generates an unchecked warning (§5.1.9) if erasure changes the field's type.

So the answer to your question basically seems to be "[erasure](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108979) could result in unchecked warnings in the presence of raw types".  As far as I can tell, this is most likely to occur when nested types are used - I can't see anywhere else in the definition of erasure that would likely cause a type to change, but perhaps someone else can suggest whether that is or isn't the source of this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for confusion. Please see my text again.