# Calling an overloaded java generic method from scala

Tags: java, generics, scala, mockito

I'm using Mockito to mock an object with a method which returns an un-parametrized ArrayList, and I cannot figure out how to get this to work

**Method signature to mock**

```
public java.util.ArrayList getX()
```

**Test code**

```
var mockee = mock(classOf[Mockee])
when(mockee.getX).thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(x): ArrayList[_])
```

This actually compiles fine in IntelliJ, but at runtime throws:

```
[error] ....scala:89: overloaded method value thenReturn with alternatives:
[error]   (java.util.ArrayList[?0],<repeated...>[java.util.ArrayList[?0]])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[java.util.ArrayList[?0]] <and>
[error]   (java.util.ArrayList[?0])org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing[java.util.ArrayList[?0]]
[error]  cannot be applied to (java.util.ArrayList[_$1])
[error]       when(mockee.getX).thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList(x): ArrayList[_])
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought `ArrayList[_]` in Scala is not the same as an unparameterized ArrayList, it is an existential type -- ie it has a type parameter, but it's bound at a funny place. I think the unparameterized type would be `ArrayList[AnyRef]` ie parameterized by `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: This looks like a compile-time error, not a run-time error. Scala's existential type `ArrayList[_]` is its closest approximation to Java's wildcard type `ArrayList<?>`. You actually have a *raw type*, `ArrayList`. Two SO questions to look into: [Scala's existential types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031042/scalas-existential-types) and [Raw types and wildcard...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489947/raw-types-unbounded-wilcard-and-bounded-wildcard)

Comment: You're right it is a compile time error, but not highlighted by the scala plugin.  I can work around this by using `thenAnswer(new Answer[ArrayList[_]]{ def answer(arg: InvocationOnMock) = Lists.newArrayList(x)})` but that's not very nice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
val mockee = mock(classOf[Mockee])
when[ArrayList[_]](mockee.getX).thenReturn(Lists.newArrayList)
```

assuming the "Lists" class is from the Google collections (now Guava).

Comment: Perfect - I never thought to add the method parameter